# Visual Studio 2012 automatically opens specific files on start

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

There are about 6 files that are automatically opened every time I launch Visual Studio 2012, even though they are already closed by me in the previous session. How can I make it so that those files no longer automatically open upon each launch, so I no longer have to manually close them?

Comment: Are you using "Show Empty Environment" for your startup setting for Visual Studio options?

Answer (score 5):

Open documents and similar user options are stored in a .suo file in the same directory with your .sln file. If your specific .suo file became corrupted, you can try to manually delete it.

Comment: Just make sure you make a backup first, I answered a question with this answer a couple of years ago and the OP was a little upset because it required him to relink all of his solution's files with his source control. So the best advise is to rename it or copy it that way it is easy to go back if it causes more problems than it solves. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure close your files and "**save your project**" again. This should fix it.

Comment: It is not working. I did save every time before I quite the VS 2012. It just keeps coming back. It looks like it writes to some kind of setting and it remembers me state. BTW, all my previous break points are coming back as well, although I deleted them at all and save the changes.

Comment: I got in to similar problem... where I was closing files but during project close skipping save. and everything was getting same set of files.. so I thought same issue.. nevermind.