# Source File Tabs on Startup

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Every time I start a Visual Studio 2013 solution it automatically opens some source files as tabs. These tabs I had opened at one point but are no longer relevant to what I am working on. I can't figure out how to get rid of these tabs (or change which ones open by default) on start up. Right now I am right clicking and selecting "Close all Documents" which works fine but I would rather not do this every time I come back to coding. Does anyone know how to change this?

Note: I am using Git Extensions and a Productivity Power Tools 2013 if this makes any difference.

Comment: Check a .suo file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264061/visual-studio-2012-automatically-opens-specific-files-on-start

Comment: Yeah that did the trick. This question was an exact duplicate of the one you linked.

Answer (score 0):

Is this when you open every solution or when you launch the IDE? If it is the latter, can you check you `Startup` options and make sure that the `At startup` option is **not set** to `Load last loaded solution`?
[image]