# How to remove recently opened files in a visual studio 2013 solution

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I noticed that whenever I open a particular Visual Studio solution it automatically opens the files that I previously worked on. The issue is that it always opens the same files, even though I have moved on to work on other files.

Is there a way to remove these "recent" files so that no files are opened at all?

Comment: Check this link...
http://abhijitannaldas.com/2014/03/clear-visual-studio-recent-project-list/

Comment: Hi Nicholas the issue is not with the list of recent projects but the list of files once I open a solution.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264061/visual-studio-2012-automatically-opens-specific-files-on-start

Comment: You are working on file1, file2 in Visual Studio (VS). You save files & close VS. Now when you open VS, you don't want VS to open file1 & file2 tabs since you have started working on other files. Have you started working on other files outside VS or within VS? Or is it that you have finished your work/coding on file1 & file2, & dont want it anymore to be opened?

Comment: @SergeyVlasov: Thanks for the link, it worked when I deleted the .suo-file. As mentioned in the link it is probably a good idea to backup the file before deleting it, although I did not need the backup.

If you like the rep you can post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @SergeyVlasov referred to in the comments, deleting the suo-file worked for me. I'm posting this answer for anyone interested.

It probably goes without saying but keeping a backup of the file is probably a good idea.