# Visual Studio 2017 unpinned tabs keep returning

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2017.  I was recently so excited to learn of the option in Tools>>Options>>Tabs And Windows>>"Show pinned tabs in a separate row".  I was doing a project that crossed a dozen files, and this option helped me organize my file well excellently.  Now I wish I'd never encountered it.  I've moved on to another project, and I can't get rid of them!  Here's (in a nutshell) what happens:

1. I unpin tabs A, B, and C from the well, and hit the X to close them.
2. I pin tabs D, E, and F (different files, same solution, various projects).
3. I save all, rebuild the solution, and restart Visual Studio
4. tabs A, B, and C are repinned again, and D, E, and F are gone.

I should note that the option "Maintain pin status if document is removed from well" appears to have no effect on this.  Please, lend me your chainsaws so I can kill these zombie tabs!

Comment: This sounds more like a bug.. I'd recommend actually reporting it on an appropriate MSDN portal.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264061/visual-studio-2012-automatically-opens-specific-files-on-start and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33322983/visual-studio-not-saving-startup-project-and-solution-config

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has this same issue...

To fix this, I had to go into my solution folder, locate the hidden .suo file, and rename it to ".suo.old".  A new .suo was generated when I closed Visual Studio, and then on next open it finally updated the well.  Hopefully I won't have to keep doing this every time I want to change my pinned files.  Does anyone have a better solution?

As others have mentioned, don't just delete the .suo without backing it up, as it could cause issues with your source control for that solution.